# porque al instanciar en alumno docente me da error pero al instanciar el curso me sale normal?

Tags: java, poo

[image: porque al instanciar en alumno docente me da error pero al instanciar el curso me sale normal?]
porque al instanciar en  alumno docente me da error pero al instanciar el curso me sale normal?

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor tu código como texto, pues como imagen es muy poco legible

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se encuentra en querer invocar muchos métodos en una sola línea. Es decir, estas llamando a un método de la clase en la misma instanciación del objeto.

Mi solción:

```
 Alumno a1 = new Alumno("Cristhian", "Chavez", 72137263, "");
 Docente d1 = new Docente("", "", 55, "");
 Curso c1 = new Curso("9741854", "POO", 4);
 c1.agregarDocente(d1);
 a1.agregarCurso(c1);
```

Comment: No creo que uno o mil métodos en la misma línea tenga algo que ver con un error en Java… de hecho, puedes compilar programas de Java que no contengan ni un sólo salto de línea.